# Python 3.8.1 - PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, windows, permissions, permission-denied

I'm trying to upload some files to Dropbox using Python and the Dropbox api.

This is what I have so far -

```
import sys
import dropbox
import time

from dropbox.files import WriteMode
from dropbox.exceptions import ApiError, AuthError


# Access dropboxToken
dropboxToken = '<token>'

localPath = '<local path in Downloads folder>'
uploadPath = '<dropbox path>'


# Uploads contents of localFile to Dropbox
def upload():
    with open(localPath, 'rb') as f:
        for file in localPath:
            # We use WriteMode=overwrite to make sure that the settings in the file
            # are changed on upload
            print('Uploading ' + localFile + ' to Dropbox location ' + uploadPath)
            try:
                dbx.files_upload(f.read(), uploadPath, mode=WriteMode('overwrite'))
            except ApiError as err:
                # This checks for the specific error where a user doesn't have enough Dropbox space quota to upload this file
                if (err.error.is_path() and
                        err.error.get_path().error.is_insufficient_space()):
                    sys.exit('ERROR: Cannot upload file; insufficient space.')
                elif err.user_message_text:
                    print(err.user_message_text)
                    sys.exit()
                else:
                    print(err)
                    sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Uploading file(s)...')
    # upload the files
    upload()
```

Whenever I run it I receive the following message: `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`

I've read some other threads about running IDLE as admin, executing the file from the command line as admin, checking the permissions of the file path, etc. but none of those suggestions are working. Is there something wrong with my code, or something else I'm not thinking of?

I'm on Windows 10 and my account is a local administrator, and I'm using Python 3.8.1. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should know that in Windows, there are some path that you can't write, add, ... to it, even you have the administrator privilege. Example, you CAN'T add any file to the `C:\\`, `C:\\Program Files`, `C:\\Program Files (x86)`, ... So the solution here is try to upload in the other path (copy your folder to another place first, like `C:\Users\user\Documents`

Comment: Thank you @EthicalHackerMinh, I'll give this a shot!